# How to list Roles that has Policy type: "AWS managed policy"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I just started to administer AWS. And would like to see good example how to list Roles of specific type.

Answer (score 4):

To list out roles managed by AWS you can do this by using the `list-roles` command and setting the path prefix to `aws-service-role`

`aws iam list-roles --path-prefix /aws-service-role/`

To query for roles utilizing a certain `policyA` inside the role declaration, I'm afraid there is no clean, one-liner to achieve the filtering you'd like. However, you can utilize the `list-attached-role-policies` command to get policy names per role listed with the `list-roles` command to do some JSON based filtering.

Hope this helps!

[list-roles documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-roles.html)
[list-attached-role-policies documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-attached-role-policies.html)

Edit: Updated answer after re-reading the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list-entities-for-policy command

```
aws iam list-entities-for-policy --policy-arn <ARN>
```

If you are using managed policies it will look like this

```
aws iam list-entities-for-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess
```

If you created the managed policy the you will need to include the Account number in the ARN like

```
aws iam list-entities-for-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::012345678910:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole-test1
```

An easy way to get the ARN

```
aws iam list-policies --output=text | grep  AdministratorAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jin's answer is better. I've inadvertently answered a slightly different question, which is how to get a list of managed policies]

The [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is your friend. For example:

```
aws iam list-policies
```

This lists all the managed policies that are available in your AWS account, including your own customer-defined managed policies and all AWS managed policies.

You can also use any one of the [supported SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/)s to implement the equivalent API call ([ListPolicies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListPolicies.html)).